# How to repeat same template in table-row using XSL-FO/Apache FOP

Tags: java, xml, pdf, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I'm trying to create a PDF from an XML file I've got and it's working fairly well so far using XSL-FO/Apache FOP.

The XML file basically contains barcode information: the barcode itself and the barcode type (I'll add the barcode image at some point as well).

Now what I'd like to see as the output is this:

```
 -----------------------
| barcode1  | barcode2  |
| codetype1 | codetype2 |
 -----------------------
| barcode3  | barcode4  |
| codetype3 | codetype4 |
 -----------------------
```

And so on.

I've defined the following xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.1" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" exclude-result-prefixes="fo">
  <xsl:template match="barcode-list">
    <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
      <fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="simpleA4" page-height="29.7cm" page-width="21cm" margin-top="2cm" margin-bottom="2cm" margin-left="2cm" margin-right="2cm">
          <fo:region-body/>
        </fo:simple-page-master>
      </fo:layout-master-set>
      <fo:page-sequence master-reference="simpleA4">
        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
          <fo:block font-size="10pt">
          <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%" border-collapse="separate">    
            <fo:table-column column-width="45%"/>
            <fo:table-column column-width="45%"/>
            <fo:table-body>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="item"/>
            </fo:table-body>
          </fo:table>
          </fo:block>
        </fo:flow>
      </fo:page-sequence>
     </fo:root>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="item">
    <fo:table-row>   
      <fo:table-cell>
        <fo:block wrap-option="wrap">
          <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
        </fo:block>
        <fo:block wrap-option="wrap">
          <xsl:value-of select="format"/>
        </fo:block>
      </fo:table-cell> 
    </fo:table-row>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So there are two columns and I assumed I could just point it at the "item" template to fill in the cells.

Now I realize that the "item" template contains a `<table-row>` tag and that that causes each item to appear in its own table row. So what I get is this:

```
 -----------------------
| barcode1  |           |
| codetype1 |           |
 -----------------------
| barcode2  |           |
| codetype2 |           |
 -----------------------
| barcode3  |           |
| codetype3 |           |
 -----------------------
| barcode4  |           |
| codetype4 |           |
 -----------------------
```

My question is how to change the xsl to get the desired output rather than getting each item in its own table row?

Comment: XSLT 1.1 was a draft that didn't go anywhere and was superseded by XSLT 2.0 and now/soon by XSLT 3.0.  Which XSLT processor are you using?  Also, `exclude-result-prefixes="fo"` effectively does nothing since every element in your output is in the `fo` namespace, which means that the XSLT processor has to include the namespace in the result.  Lastly, the `xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"` on the `fo:root` is within the scope of the `xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"` on the `xsl:stylesheet`, so it isn't strictly necessary and doesn't affect the output.

Comment: @TonyGraham If I remove either of the two elements from the file, Apache FOP throws an exception complaining about unbound elements and unknown tags.

Comment: @TonyGraham What changes would I have to apply to the document to make it XSLT 2.0 compliant?

Comment: An exception seems odd.  Removing the `@exclude-result-prefixes` and removing the `xmlns:fo` from the `fo:root` should work, but since changing things generates exceptions, it is safer to not change things.  From what you've shown, you could just change the `@version` value to `2.0`.  There are some edge cases listed in Appendix J of the XSLT 2.0 spec, but most XSLT 1.0 stylesheets work fine in an XSLT 2.0 processor after a version number change.  You should, of course, test that the output doesn't change after you change the version number.

Comment: @TonyGraham Thanks for your help. Changing the version number worked just fine. BTW: The exception I got was: "The prefix "fo" for element "fo:table-cell" is not bound"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Omit the `fo:table-row` and use the rarely-used `starts-row` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#starts-row) and/or `ends-row` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#ends-row) properties:

```
<xsl:template match="item">
  <fo:table-cell>
    <xsl:if test="position() mod 2 = 1">
      <xsl:attribute name="starts-row">true</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:if>
    <fo:block wrap-option="wrap">
      <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
    </fo:block>
    <fo:block wrap-option="wrap">
      <xsl:value-of select="format"/>
    </fo:block>
  </fo:table-cell> 
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: That pretty much does the job. Thank you!