# How to fill table vertically?

Tags: java, xml, pdf, xsl-fo, apache-fop

This is a follow-up question to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37674873/how-to-repeat-same-template-in-table-row-using-xsl-fo-apache-fop) I posted a while ago.

I've got the following xsl stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" exclude-result-prefixes="fo">
  <xsl:template match="barcode-list">
    <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
      <fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="simpleA4" page-height="29.7cm" page-width="21cm" margin-top="2cm" margin-bottom="2cm" margin-left="2cm" margin-right="2cm">
          <fo:region-body/>
        </fo:simple-page-master>
      </fo:layout-master-set>
      <fo:page-sequence master-reference="simpleA4">
        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
          <fo:block font-size="14pt">
          <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%" border-collapse="separate" border-separation="3pt">    
            <fo:table-column column-width="50%"/>
            <fo:table-column column-width="50%"/>
            <fo:table-body>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="item"/>
            </fo:table-body>
          </fo:table>
          </fo:block>
        </fo:flow>
      </fo:page-sequence>
     </fo:root>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="item">
    <fo:table-cell text-align="center">
      <xsl:if test="position() mod 2 = 1">
        <xsl:attribute name="starts-row">true</xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:if>
      <fo:block>
        <fo:external-graphic height="scale-to-fit" width="100%" content-height="scale-to-fit" content-width="scale-to-fit">
          <xsl:attribute name="src">url('<xsl:value-of select="image"/>')</xsl:attribute>
        </fo:external-graphic>
      </fo:block>
      <fo:block>
        <fo:external-graphic height="scale-to-fit" width="100%" content-height="scale-to-fit" content-width="scale-to-fit">
          <xsl:attribute name="src">url('<xsl:value-of select="barcode"/>')</xsl:attribute>
        </fo:external-graphic>
      </fo:block>
      <fo:block wrap-option="wrap">
        <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
      </fo:block>
    </fo:table-cell> 
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This works great, as it fills a table with two columns with my data.

This fills the table "horizontally", like the table on the left.

I re-evaluated my requirements and realized that I'd like it to be filled "vertically" like the table on the right:

```
 ---------------     -----------------
|   1   |   2   |   |   1   | (n/2)+1 |
|   3   |   4   |   |   2   | (n/2)+2 | 
|  ...  |  ...  |   |  ...  |   ...   |
|  n-1  |   n   |   |  n/2  |    n    |
 ---------------     -----------------
```

Ideally, I'd want to move to the next column at the end of the page and start anew in the first column on the next page, but I presume that's not possible.

This is an example of my xml:

```
<barcode-list>
   <item>
      <name>the-barcode</name>
      <barcode>file:///d:/pdf/barcode.png</barcode>
      <image>file:///d:/test.png</image>
      <format>CODE_128</format>
   </item>
   ...
</barcode-list>
```

I found [this](https://www.oxygenxml.com/archives/xsl-list/201109/msg00134.html) message board entry that seems to suggest a solution, but I can't wrap my head around what it does.

Can anyone give me any pointers as to how to start?

Comment: Create a two column document and not a table

Comment: @KevinBrown Would that allow me to automatically go to the next column at the end of the page or would it basically fill the first column of all the pages before it starts with the second column of the first page?

Comment: A two column document would fill the left column, then the right column, the start again on the next page and so on.

Comment: @KevinBrown Sounds pretty much like what I'm trying to achieve. Would you mind posting that as an answer? Ideally with a small example?

Comment: Ok, I will pull together s ample document with your sample layout in about an hour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a two-column document layout and your content blocks (with the two images and a label) will flow down the page, then to the next column. This would continue on subsequent pages. Below is a sample FO and result. A few things to note:

- Two columns is achieved by adding column-count to the region-body
- Each of the containers with your repeating content is within a block-container with keep-together.within-column set to "always" to ensure your two images and a label are all together and not split across columns or pages.
- I did change your graphic specification as scale-to-fit is not correct on width/height

Sample FO code (note I only an showing the first few blocks here and I numbered them to show the order):

```
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
<fo:layout-master-set>
    <fo:simple-page-master master-name="simpleA4" page-height="29.7cm" page-width="21cm" margin-top="2cm" margin-bottom="2cm" margin-left="2cm" margin-right="2cm">
        <fo:region-body column-count="2"/>
    </fo:simple-page-master>
</fo:layout-master-set>
<fo:page-sequence master-reference="simpleA4">
    <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
        <fo:block-container font-size="14pt"  text-align="center" keep-together.within-column="always">
            <fo:block>
                <fo:external-graphic src="url('box.jpg')" height="100%" width="100%" content-height="scale-to-fit" content-width="scale-to-fit"/>                   
            </fo:block>
            <fo:block>
                <fo:external-graphic src="url('brick.jpg')" height="100%" width="100%" content-height="scale-to-fit" content-width="scale-to-fit"/>
            </fo:block>
            <fo:block wrap-option="wrap">
                Object Name 1
            </fo:block>
        </fo:block-container>

        <fo:block-container font-size="14pt"  text-align="center" keep-together.within-column="always">
            <fo:block>
                <fo:external-graphic src="url('box.jpg')" height="100%" width="100%" content-height="scale-to-fit" content-width="scale-to-fit"/>                   
            </fo:block>
            <fo:block>
                <fo:external-graphic src="url('brick.jpg')" height="100%" width="100%" content-height="scale-to-fit" content-width="scale-to-fit"/>
            </fo:block>
            <fo:block wrap-option="wrap">
                Object Name 2
            </fo:block>
        </fo:block-container>
```

Sample Output for 9 blocks:

[image]

Comment: Brilliant, just what I was looking for. Thanks!